# How can I loop through a dictionary list and extract values to a single string?

Tags: python

Very new to python. I have to pull the values out and compile them to a single string for use in a text file.

List looks like this:

```
    {
        "1626296627": "ALPHA: Client/Contact Communication entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296657": "BETA: Patient Communication entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296802": "CHARLIE: Clincial Record Communication button entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296835": "DELTA: Clinical Record Communication tab communication entry\n\n"
    }
```

Comment: That's presumably a list of dicts. What is your desired output string?

Comment: Just trying to get all of the strings into a single string so I can use it as input to a txt file

Comment: So, just all the strings concatenated together? No spaces?

Comment: Essentially, they already have formatting to work properly in the txt file

Comment: Try: `''.join([list(x.values())[0] for x in mylist])`, for the values, without keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work:

```
lst = [{
        "1626296627": "ALPHA: Client/Contact Communication entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296657": "BETA: Patient Communication entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296802": "CHARLIE: Clincial Record Communication button entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296835": "DELTA: Clinical Record Communication tab communication entry\n\n"
    }]
s=''
for d in lst:
   for key in d:
      s = s + d[key]
```

Output:

```
ALPHA: Client/Contact Communication entry

BETA: Patient Communication entry

CHARLIE: Clincial Record Communication button entry

DELTA: Clinical Record Communication tab communication entry
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just concatenate everything together:

```py
data = [{
        "1626296627": "ALPHA: Client/Contact Communication entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296657": "BETA: Patient Communication entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296802": "CHARLIE: Clincial Record Communication button entry\n\n"
    },
    {
        "1626296835": "DELTA: Clinical Record Communication tab communication entry\n\n"
    }]

output = ''.join(k+v for item in data for k,v in item.items())
print(output)
```

Output:

```
1626296627ALPHA: Client/Contact Communication entry

1626296657BETA: Patient Communication entry

1626296802CHARLIE: Clincial Record Communication button entry

1626296835DELTA: Clinical Record Communication tab communication entry
```